# Output struct objects to binary file and input from it back in C

Tags: c, binary, feof

i write managment system in C.
i have this structure

```
#define STRING_LENGTH 32
typedef struct {
    char name[STRING_LENGTH];
} Name;

typedef struct{
    int id, balance;
    Name clientName;
} Client;
```

i create few test objects, open binary file for write, use `fwrite` to write objects to file, closing it and after this using `fread` into `while(!feof...` block, and my problem is that i print 4 objects to binary file, and while i read objects from file and print it to screen, last object printed twice.
what i do incorrect? i need only to write objects to file and then get them back from it.

my code:

```
FILE *clientsFile = NULL;

switch (selectedOption)
{
case CLIENT:

        clientsFile = fopen(CLIENTS_FILE_PATH, "wb");

        Client getUser;
        Client temp1 = { 1, 10000, "Alex" };
        Client temp2 = { 2, 100000, "Valery" };
        Client temp3 = { 3, 105466, "Jack" };
        Client temp4 = { 4, 1069640, "Pam" };

        fwrite(&temp1, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile);
        fwrite(&temp2, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile);
        fwrite(&temp3, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile);
        fwrite(&temp4, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile);

        fclose(clientsFile);

        clientsFile = fopen(CLIENTS_FILE_PATH, "rb");

        do
        {               
            fread(&getUser, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile);
            printf("ID : %d, Name : %s, Balance : %d\n", getUser.id, getUser.clientName.name, getUser.balance);
        } while (!feof(clientsFile));

        break;
```

output photo : [screen of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Ug6.gif)

thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way is to do it like this. If you read the correct number of records, fine, if not, quit. There is no need to involve `feof()`.

```
while(fread(&getUser, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile) == 1) {
    printf("ID : %d, Name : %s, Balance : %d\n", getUser.id, getUser.clientName.name, getUser.balance);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`feof()` returns true if the end of file indicator flag has been raised. A successful call to `fread()` will not result in raising the flag. Thus, after reading the last record, you iterate one more time.

Instead, check to see if `fread()` was successful to decide if you have reached end of file or encountered some other error.

```
    do
    {               
        if (fread(&getUser, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile) == 1) {
            printf("ID : %d, Name : %s, Balance : %d\n", getUser.id, getUser.clientName.name, getUser.balance);
        } else {
            /* do something */
        }
    } while (!feof(clientsFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using do-while.

```
do
{               
    fread(&getUser, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile);
    printf("ID : %d, Name : %s, Balance : %d\n", getUser.id, getUser.clientName.name, getUser.balance);
} while (!feof(clientsFile));
```

In this, when you read for the 5th time you get EOF. But "getUser" still has the 4th Client entry. So you get last output twice.

Solution:
Change it to while loop.

```
while (fread(&getUser, sizeof(Client), 1, clientsFile) && !feof(clientsFile))
{
    printf("ID : %d, Name : %s, Balance : %d\n", getUser.id, getUser.clientName.name, getUser.balance);
}
```

Comment: What happens if an error occurs when calling fread()? AFAICT, feof() will return 0 and the program will be stuck in an eternal loop, right?

Comment: Not very elegant because you have the exact same `fread` in two different places.

Comment: BjornA. and Micheal, I agree to both the points. Thank you.  I updated my answer. Is it fine now?